# Replacing a new line character with streamwriter remove everything after it. (ASP.NET, Json, C#)

Tags: asp.net, csv, replace, newline, streamwriter

I'm having an unexpected problem which I'm hoping one of you can help me with.

I have an ASP.NET Web API with a number of end points, one of which takes user input, received as JSON, and converts it into an order object which is written to a file in .CSV format. The following is a small snippet of the full code as an example.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file))
        {
           writer.Write(escape + order.Notes + escape + delim);
           writer.Write(escape + order.Reference1 + escape + delim);
           writer.Write(escape + order.Reference2 + escape + delim);

           writer.WriteLine();                 
           writer.Flush();
    }
```

The problem I am having is that some users are inclined to add line breaks in
certain fields, and this is causing havoc with my order file. In order to remove 
these new line characters, I have tried both of the following methods.

```
writer.Write(escape + product.Notes.Replace("\n", " ") + escape + delim);
writer.Write(escape + product.Notes.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ") + escape + delim);
```

However, it seems that, rather than just remove the new line character and carry on writing the rest of the fields, when a new line is encountered, nothing else gets written.

Either everything else gets replace with the " " or nothing else is being written at all, but I'm not sure which.

If I remove the .Replace() the whole file is written again but with extra line breaks.

I hope somebody has experienced this one and knows the answer!

Comment: In your code writer object is in using block and then outside using block your are calling flush() method with same object. How you are accessing the writer object out side the using block. except this your code looks correct and working with replace method.

Comment: Ah yes, this is actually an error in the way I've written the post, the actual code has the flush in the correct place. It's strange!

Comment: Can you please provide the original content you are converting to CSV file. With test values code working perfectly.

Comment: It receives a Json object which creates an instance of my Order class and then writes the attribute of the instance to the .csv file, I can write something in so that we can see the Json received, I'll get back to you when I have that, thanks.

Comment: You can add json response to your question so other also check and provide you solutions